# Yii don't understand how to log a message

Tags: php, logging, yii

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) but still I go to the webpage refresh, then go to the file and still I can't find the log message I sent
I wrote the following line in a controller:

```
Yii::log("Index Checkout",CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR);
```

And My configurations:

```
'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'logFile'=>'trace.log',
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error,info, warning',
                ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
              array(
              'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
              ),
             */
            ),
```

Comment: Unless you don't properly end the application, these settings would be useless. Message routing is done at the end of the request. Additionally the path to the logfile is not provided, it's just a file-name. Maybe you're looking at the wrong file?

Comment: no it did create the file, I was actually checking if it works and it did work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in a similar trouble with YII logger. Strange but I was kind of messing with parameter order.

This works for me:

```
<?php

Yii::log('', CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, 'Message Here...');
```

Comment: It's `Yii::log($message, $level, $category);`

Comment: I agree, the correct parameter order is the one you provided but the example I posted above worked fine for some reason.

Comment: @otar actually yes it worked, I know it's not right but it helped me do some debugging thanks man

Answer (score 8):

Right way to write to log is:

```
Yii::log($message, $level, $category);
```

But point is that **$category should not be empty**.

Example above works becouse message is written in category then category is not empty, but it writes empty message. It writes category so it looks like message.. but it isn't.